# C++ Builder 10.1 Android Compile Error: type_traits file not found

Tags: android, c++, c++11, c++builder

I created a Multi-Device Application in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin. Then I compiled this project for android platform. My project is only form, no code. (New Multi-Device App C++ and compile).

I am getting this error message:

> [bccaarm Fatal Error] sysmac.h(1465): 'type_traits' file not found

I know this error for C++11 but how can I set C++11 in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: bccaarm is a C++11 compiler, you don't have to do anything extra to set it to C++11. I don't have Berlin installed yet, what does line 1465 of `sysmac.h` actually look like?

Comment: Look at the picture: [link](http://s32.postimg.org/5n12szgxh/cppbuilderberlinerror.png). Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched your IDE installation folders to make sure a `type_traits` file exists?  If so, then your project's includes path is likely not configured correctly.

Comment: I couldn't find reason of the error. I looked at the installation folders but there isn't type_traits file.

Comment: Then you *do* have a reason: the `type_traits` file is not installed. Maybe your IDE install is incomplete, try reinstalling again. Or file a bug report to Embarcadero with [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com). `type_traits` is a standard C++11 header file, so it should be present. Boost (which you can install via GetIt) also has its own `type_traits` file, if you want to try installing that.

Comment: Several versions of `type_traits` are installed as part of ***Android NDK***, But I was not able to make any of them work correctly either.